# How to extend ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, gparted

[ubuntu gparted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trvAy.png)

How to move unallocated space into my ubuntu partition which is /dev/sda6?
I have important data on my ubuntu partition and don't won't loose anything, I just want to extend that partition.

https://d.pr/v/5m9csF

Comment: To extend sda6, you FIRST have to make a backup of your important files there. Moving/resizing partitions CAN LOOSE DATA. Then the process is somewhat complicated, and I can outline it for you, but I want to hear that you've done a backup first. What version of Windows do you have installed?

Comment: I have a W10 on sd2. Windows is not that important so if I loose something on Windows, no big deal. Only important thing now is sd6 which is my ubuntu system that I don't want to loose and only extend that partition with this 99GB in unallocated space.

Comment: Do you have a backup yet? Here's another problem though. Windows 10 updates can easily wipe out ext4 partitions on a MBR partitioned disk. And you really need to keep Windows to do some things. Do you have the Windows license key and install disc? If so, I'd recommend setting your BIOS to UEFI mode, init the drive in GPT partition mode, and reinstall Windows and Ubuntu fresh, with the partitioning that you'd like. Then restore your data.

Answer (score 0):

- Boot either a Ubuntu or GParted Live CD.
- Open GParted.
- Right-click on the partition you wish to shrink.
- Select Resize.
- Shrink or Delete the target partition (make sure you leave at least a couple of GB for an OS to play with, especially Windows, unless you're deleting it completely).
- Click Apply (tick at the right of the icons along the top, this might take a while, and you can't undo or stop it half-way through).
- Right-click on your Ubuntu Partition.
- Expand into all the free space.
  Click Apply again.

Comment: https://d.pr/v/5m9csF

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/221232/how-do-i-move-this-unallocated-space-to-the-beginning-of-the-disk

Comment: The 'lock' symbol means that you skipped the first step of the answer.

Comment: **This answer is incomplete, and somewhat dangerous.**